# dblclick on marker not working at all

Tags: marker

i am just doing my first experiences with maps api. Works great, but...

adding a click event to a marker works, adding a dblclick ... nothings happens. As if the dblclick simply doesnt fire.

So my questions:

Is a marker capable to handle a dblclick?

Sample code is as follows (the catch exception e doesnt make any change) :

```
try
{
    if (urlfuerdoppelclick != null)
        if (urlfuerdoppelclick.Length > 0)
        {
            eintraege = eintraege + " marker" + i.ToString() + ".addListener";
            eintraege = eintraege + " ('dblclick',";
            eintraege = eintraege + "   function () ";
            eintraege = eintraege + "    { ";
            eintraege = eintraege + "      window.open(\"" + urlfuerdoppelclick 
+ "\"); ";
            eintraege = eintraege + "    } ";
            eintraege = eintraege + " ); ";
        }
}
catch { };
try
{
    if (voninnen != null)
        if (voninnen.Length > 0)
        {
            eintraege = eintraege + " marker" + i.ToString() + ".addListener";
            eintraege = eintraege + " ('click',";
            eintraege = eintraege + "   function () ";
            eintraege = eintraege + "    { ";
            eintraege = eintraege + "      window.open(\"" + voninnen + "\"); ";
            eintraege = eintraege + "    } ";
            eintraege = eintraege + " ); ";
        };
}
catch (Exception e) { };
```

Comment: the missing } has now been inserted

Comment: Please clean up the code by editing - remove extra newlines, put all code together into code section...

Comment: @Stefan .. when omitting the extra linefeed all code had been displayed as one long line, so i inserted them

Comment: i re-edited, now it works without extra linefeed. Your Editor is funny.